# How to care for Indian Flapshell Turtle

Tags: turtles

I gave recently found a indian flpashell turtle on road side and hence I have brought it home. So please guide me about how to treat him and food and how Shall I keep him in water or Land

Comment: ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IniKV.jpg)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OwWP.jpg)
This is which turtle please guide.

Comment: It is indian Flapshess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are wonderful creatures to have as a pet. I have owned a turtle since 15 years. He is usually kept inside a tank, but I take him out for an hour or half at least once a day. He usually eats all the worms inside the tank, but I also provide him small pieces of wheat flour; there are various turtle foods  available in the market, so you can also feed them that. They can live in both land and water too.  Mine also loves to sit on my lap and even on the bed.